# Convert nested list to dataframe when reading json file

Tags: r, json, list

I am trying to import data from two sensors (many more actually but this is just a test case). The final product should be a data frame or table that has 4 columns - two for each sensor. One is the time of the data collection, the other is the return data.  I can't include the url that accesses the data because it includes keys for access but the start looks like this `https://api.ecowitt.net/api/v3/device/history`
The following code runs fine

```
response <- httr::GET(url_complete_noDates, query = list(start_date = "2022-07-01 00:00:00", end_date = "2022-07-01 02:00:00"))

jsonRespText <- content(response, as =  "text") 
j <- fromJSON(jsonRespText)
```

But I can't figure out how to parse this into a data frame. This gets close

```
j_data <- j$data
df_json1 <- as_tibble(j_data, validate = F) 
temp_unnest <- df_json1 %>% unnest(cols = names(df_json1))
```

Here is the dput output for j. The time value is the time of the data download in seconds from 1970-01-01-00:00 MDT. Each element like this - `1656655200` = "38" is the time/data point that should go in a row of the the data frame.

```
list(code = 0L, msg = "success", time = "1673535777", data = list(
    soil_ch1 = list(soilmoisture = list(unit = "%", list = list(
        `1656655200` = "38", `1656657000` = "38", `1656658800` = "38", 
        `1656660600` = "38", `1656662400` = "38"))), soil_ch2 = list(
        soilmoisture = list(unit = "%", list = list(`1656655200` = "48", 
            `1656657000` = "48", `1656658800` = "48", `1656660600` = "48", 
            `1656662400` = "48")))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the nested list into a `data.frame`, reshape it to the name-value format with `pivot_longer`, and `separate` the name column into multiple columns with the separators `"\\."`.

```r
library(tidyr)

as.data.frame(j$data) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  separate(name, paste0("col", 1:4), sep = '\\.', fill = 'right')

# # A tibble: 12 × 5
#    col1     col2         col3  col4       value
#    <chr>    <chr>        <chr> <chr>      <chr>
#  1 soil_ch1 soilmoisture unit  NA         %    
#  2 soil_ch1 soilmoisture list  1656655200 38   
#  3 soil_ch1 soilmoisture list  1656657000 38   
#  4 soil_ch1 soilmoisture list  1656658800 38   
#  5 soil_ch1 soilmoisture list  1656660600 38   
#  6 soil_ch1 soilmoisture list  1656662400 38   
#  7 soil_ch2 soilmoisture unit  NA         %    
#  8 soil_ch2 soilmoisture list  1656655200 48   
#  9 soil_ch2 soilmoisture list  1656657000 48   
# 10 soil_ch2 soilmoisture list  1656658800 48   
# 11 soil_ch2 soilmoisture list  1656660600 48   
# 12 soil_ch2 soilmoisture list  1656662400 48
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, melting the nested list into a long data.frame with `reshape2::melt()`:

```
reshape2::melt(j_data)
#>         value         L5   L4           L3       L2   L1
#> 1           0       <NA> <NA>         <NA>     <NA> code
#> 2     success       <NA> <NA>         <NA>     <NA>  msg
#> 3  1673535777       <NA> <NA>         <NA>     <NA> time
#> 4           %       <NA> unit soilmoisture soil_ch1 data
#> 5          38 1656655200 list soilmoisture soil_ch1 data
#> 6          38 1656657000 list soilmoisture soil_ch1 data
#> 7          38 1656658800 list soilmoisture soil_ch1 data
#> 8          38 1656660600 list soilmoisture soil_ch1 data
#> 9          38 1656662400 list soilmoisture soil_ch1 data
#> 10          %       <NA> unit soilmoisture soil_ch2 data
#> 11         48 1656655200 list soilmoisture soil_ch2 data
#> 12         48 1656657000 list soilmoisture soil_ch2 data
#> 13         48 1656658800 list soilmoisture soil_ch2 data
#> 14         48 1656660600 list soilmoisture soil_ch2 data
#> 15         48 1656662400 list soilmoisture soil_ch2 data
```

Or to have more control in melting the nested list, we could use `rrapply()` in package `rrapply`:

```
rrapply::rrapply(
  j_data, 
  condition = \(x, .xname) !.xname %in% c("code", "msg", "time", "unit"),
  f = as.numeric,
  how = "melt"
)
#>      L1       L2           L3   L4         L5 value
#> 1  data soil_ch1 soilmoisture list 1656655200    38
#> 2  data soil_ch1 soilmoisture list 1656657000    38
#> 3  data soil_ch1 soilmoisture list 1656658800    38
#> 4  data soil_ch1 soilmoisture list 1656660600    38
#> 5  data soil_ch1 soilmoisture list 1656662400    38
#> 6  data soil_ch2 soilmoisture list 1656655200    48
#> 7  data soil_ch2 soilmoisture list 1656657000    48
#> 8  data soil_ch2 soilmoisture list 1656658800    48
#> 9  data soil_ch2 soilmoisture list 1656660600    48
#> 10 data soil_ch2 soilmoisture list 1656662400    48
```

Instead, we can also unnest to a wide data.frame if that is more appropriate:

```
rrapply::rrapply(
  j_data, 
  how = "bind", 
  options = list(coldepth = 5, namecols = TRUE)
)
#>     L1       L2           L3   L4 1656655200 1656657000 1656658800 1656660600 1656662400
#> 1 data soil_ch1 soilmoisture list         38         38         38         38         38
#> 2 data soil_ch2 soilmoisture list         48         48         48         48         48
```